# Haskell: Show instance of IOArray

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and trying to use mutable arrays (in particular `IOArray`). I wrote a pretty printer that has the following type:

```
disp :: Show a => IOArray Int a -> IO String
```

I didn't manage to get rid of the `IO` part because of a subcall to

```
getBounds :: Ix i => a i e -> m (i, i)
```

Now I'm trying to use `disp` to define a `Show` instance for my `IOArray` type but the `IO` gets in the way.

Is it possible to create a `Show` instance for `IOArray` ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can't take a value out of the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IOArray` is not really an array. It's just a *reference* to an array. Absolutely everything interesting you can do with an `IOArray` produces an action in `IO`. Why is that? Suppose you could index into an `IOArray` in pure code:

```
(!) :: IOArray Int a -> a
```

Consider the following:

```
f :: IO (Char, Char)
f = do
  ar <- newArray (0 :: Int, 10 :: Int) 'a'
  let x = ar ! 3
  writeArray ar 3 'b'
  let y = ar ! 3
  return (x, y)
```

What should `f` produce? One answer might be that it should produce `('a', 'b')`, because the third element of `ar` started out as `'a'` and then was changed to `'b'`. But that's deeply troubling! How can `ar ! 3` have one value at one time and another later? That violates the fundamental idea of referential transparency that purely functional languages are built on. So you just can't do that.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was expecting without being sure. So basically I have to call my "show" function by hand, I can't create an instance of `Show`. I'll try to look around if there is an existing pattern for this problem. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK in Haskell getting rid of Monads is neither possible nor correct. Some monads (like Maybe and Either) has special methods to unwrap their values, but (over)using them is discouraged. If you have any Haskell type that is wrapped within a Monad context, you must use it and work with it without unwrapping and releasing. For your case, any type within an IO monad, can not be converted (using any type of function like Show) to any type without IO Monad. One solution for your case is using Haskell's rich treasure of Monad functions and operators to convert inner type (e.g. Int) to Char, and after that you have a IO String instead of IOArray, which in turn you can print out.

Comment: This has only a little to do with monads and everything to do with these *particular* monads.